Argument type error with extended record properties
I'm trying to create a generic EventEmitter class in TypeScript. I encountered an interesting issue when I tried to add additional events to my subclass.
Here is a simple example:
class EventEmitter<TEvents extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> {
    public emit<TType extends keyof TEvents>(
        type: TType,
        ...data: TEvents[TType] extends void ? [] : [data: TEvents[TType]]
    ) {
        console.log(type, data)
    }
}

class Foo<TEvents extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> extends EventEmitter<TEvents & {
    foo: string;
    empty: void;
}> {
    testFoo() {
        this.emit("foo", "123");
        // Error: Argument of type '["123"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 
        // '(TEvents & { foo: string; empty: void; })["foo"] extends void ? [] : [data: (TEvents & { foo: string; empty: void; })["foo"]]'.

        this.emit("empty"); // Works
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo<{ bar: number }> {
    testBar() {
        this.emit("bar", 123); // Works
        this.emit("foo", "123"); // Works
        this.emit("empty"); // Works
    }
}

Error:
Argument of type '["123"]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(TEvents & { foo: string; empty: void; })["foo"] extends void ? [] : [data: (TEvents & { foo: string; empty: void; })["foo"]]'.

I have tried omitting existing keys, prettify, removed void check, but nothing seems to work.
Even something like this doesn't work
interface FooEvents extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown> {
    foo: number;
}

class Foo<TEvents extends FooEvents> extends EventEmitter<TEvents> {
    testFoo() {
        this.emit("foo", 123);
        // Error: Argument of type '[123]' is not assignable to parameter of type
        // '(TEvents & { foo: number; })["foo"] extends void ? [] : [data: (TEvents & { foo: number; })["foo"]]'.
    }
}

Also none of the following definitions don't limit Bar from extending with foo property:
type FooEvents = {
    foo: string;
    empty: void;
}

class Foo<TEvents extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> extends EventEmitter<FooEvents & Omit<TEvents, keyof FooEvents>>

// or

class Foo<TEvents extends Record<Exclude<PropertyKey, keyof FooEvents>, unknown>> extends EventEmitter<FooEvent & TEvents> 

// or

class Foo<TEvents extends Omit<Record<PropertyKey, keyof FooEvents>, keyof FooEvents>, unknown> extends EventEmitter<FooEvents & FooEvents> 

class Bar extends Foo<{ bar: number, foo: number }> 

Is this even possible? Otherwise I will just have to resort to one events definition for all subclasses.

Basically, the generic TEvents confuses the interpretation of Foo in Foo.testFoo. The type declaration itself seems logical. And since what you wrote seems logical, I started searching for active issues, and soon I came across open requests:

Support forwarding generic type in extending class #41719 - GitHub (microsoft/typescript)

I worked around this issue by inserting a Facade, in which I declare the class just like you did, and then if you want to create testFoo in Foo, you can do so using the Facade. I'll show you:
type EventRecord = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;

class EventEmitter<TEvents extends EventRecord> {
  public emit<TType extends keyof TEvents>(
    type: TType,
    ...data: TEvents[TType] extends void ? [] : [data: TEvents[TType]]
  ): void {
    console.log(type, data);
  }
}

class Facade<TEvents extends EventRecord = {}> extends EventEmitter<
  TEvents & { foo: string; test: number; empty: void }
> {}

class Foo extends Facade {
  testFoo() {
    this.emit("foo", "123");
    this.emit("test", 23);
    this.emit("empty");
  }
}

class Bar extends Facade<{ bar: boolean }> {
  testBar() {
    this.emit("foo", "123");
    this.emit("test", 23);
    this.emit("empty");
    this.emit("bar", true);
  }
}

I've reworked the EventEmitter a bit into a more supported function, just out of curiosity. Now, it's clear that the code fails when using the TEvents generic in the extend-class:
type EventRecord = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;

function EventEmitter<TEvents extends EventRecord>() {
  return class {
    public emit<TType extends keyof TEvents>(
      type: TType,
      ...data: TEvents[TType] extends void ? [] : [data: TEvents[TType]]
    ): void {
      console.log(type, data);
    }
  };
}

const Facade = <TEvents extends EventRecord>() => EventEmitter<
  TEvents & { foo: string; test: number; empty: void }
>();

// ERROR: Base class expressions cannot reference class type parameters.ts(2562)
//                                                     [here]
class Foo<TEvents extends EventRecord> extends Facade<TEvents & { customEvent: string }>() {
  testFoo() {
    this.emit("foo", "123");
    this.emit("test", 23);
    this.emit("empty");
    this.emit("customEvent", "hello");
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo<{ bar: boolean }> {
  testBar() {
    this.emit("foo", "123");
    this.emit("test", 23);
    this.emit("empty");
    this.emit("bar", true);
  }
}

Ultimately, similarly, if Facade is declared separately, it could work:
type EventRecord = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;

function EventEmitter<TEvents extends EventRecord>() {
  return class {
    public emit<TType extends keyof TEvents>(
      type: TType,
      ...data: TEvents[TType] extends void ? [] : [data: TEvents[TType]]
    ): void {
      console.log(type, data);
    }
  };
}

const Facade = <TEvents extends EventRecord>() => EventEmitter<
  TEvents & { foo: string; test: number; empty: void }
>();

class Foo extends Facade<{ customEvent: string }>() {
  testFoo() {
    this.emit("foo", "123");
    this.emit("test", 23);
    this.emit("empty");
    this.emit("customEvent", "hello");
  }
}

class Bar extends Facade<{ bar: boolean }>() {
  testBar() {
    this.emit("foo", "123");
    this.emit("test", 23);
    this.emit("empty");
    this.emit("bar", true);
  }
}

Final conclusion: Perhaps the syntax does indeed become too complicated by ensuring that TEvents is not interpreted by Foo on its own, but is interpreted if Foo is already just a sub-class. I believe that depending on the intended use case, you can lean towards a simpler, more suitable alternative for you.
